# set cookie to expire at the end of current day

Tags: php, cookies, time, mktime

I want to set a cookie and have it expire at the end of the day

This works, but expires after 24 hours:

```
setcookie('route_upgrade_voted', true, time()+86400);
```

This does not work:

```
setcookie('route_upgrade_voted', true,  mktime(24,0,0) - time());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie expiry times are an ABSOLUTE value, based on time since jan 1/1970. You're sending over a relative one: "tomorrow's time minus the current time". This translates into basically the number of seconds left between now and midnight, which is then interpreted as a date back in Jan 1/1970. You don't need to subtract `time()` at all:

```
echo date('r', mktime(24,0,0)), ' ',  date('r');
                             ^--note: no subtraction
Tue, 28 Jan 2014 00:00:00 -0600 Mon, 27 Jan 2014 13:30:33 -0600
```

And poof, you have "tomorrow at midnight", v.s. today's current date/time. So:

```
setcookie(..., mktime(24,0,0));
```

Answer (score 12):

The easiest would be:

```
setcookie('route_upgrade_voted', true, strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

I hope this helps :)