# How to set expiration of a cookie at the end of the day (next.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I'm using react-cookies and I'd like to let a cookie expire at the end of the day (not after 24hrs or at the end of a session BUT at the end of the day).

Here's how I set the cookie:

```
setCookies("dailyCookie", {
    path: "/",
    maxAge: // should expire at the end of the day, 
    sameSite: true,
  });
```

I haven't found the right solution, yet (similar questions: [set cookie to expire at the end of current day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389831/set-cookie-to-expire-at-the-end-of-current-day)). Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8636617/10221765 to get the end of the day?

Comment: [More examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=cookie+expire+end+of+day+site:stackoverflow.com)